# Most Pythonic Way to Split an Array by Repeating Elements

Tags: python

I have a list of items that I want to split based on a delimiter. I want all delimiters to be removed and the list to be split when a **delimiter occurs twice**.  For example, if the delimiter is `'X'`, then the following list:

```
['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g']
```

Would turn into:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']]
```

Notice that the last set is not split.

I've written some ugly code that does this, but I'm sure there is something nicer. Extra points if you can set an arbitrary length delimiter (i.e. split the list after seeing N delimiters).

Comment: What should happen with less than N delimiters? Are they simply removed (without splitting)?

Comment: @MichaelMior - yes, they are just removed (see the third subgroup). And "fewer" is the word you were looking for.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Yes, I saw the example. But I'm asking the OP to clarify since I don't want to generalize based on one example.

Comment: What should happen with more than N delimiters? Are the excess ones just removed? If there are 2*N delimiters, should an extra empty sublist be created?

Comment: I suppose my question doesn't define what happens if there are more than N delimiters, so the program can do what it wants.  That said, it would probably make sense to either (1) create empty lists or (2) ignore the additional delimiters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there's going to be a nice, elegant solution to this (I'd love to be proven wrong of course) so I would suggest something straightforward:

```
def nSplit(lst, delim, count=2):
    output = [[]]
    delimCount = 0
    for item in lst:
        if item == delim:
            delimCount += 1
        elif delimCount >= count:
            output.append([item])
            delimCount = 0
        else:
            output[-1].append(item)
            delimCount = 0
    return output
```

```
>>> nSplit(['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g'], 'X', 2)
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']]
```

Comment: I like this one, cleaner than my original.  I guess my original post was unclear, but I wanted it to do the split when the delimiter occurs twice in a row, not just twice.  The code above can be modified to do so, all you need to do is set `delimCount = 0` in the `else` branch.

Comment: If there are 4 'X's in a row in the input, should there be an empty list in the output? If so, this solution does not do this.

Comment: @speedplane Yes, that was a mistake on my part. Fixed now

Comment: @PaulMcGuire If that is the desired behavior, it's fairly easy to get: just change `elif` into `if`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it with `itertools.groupby()`:

```
import itertools

class MultiDelimiterKeyCallable(object):
    def __init__(self, delimiter, num_wanted=1):
        self.delimiter = delimiter
        self.num_wanted = num_wanted

        self.num_found = 0

    def __call__(self, value):
        if value == self.delimiter:
            self.num_found += 1
            if self.num_found >= self.num_wanted:
                self.num_found = 0
                return True
        else:
            self.num_found = 0

def split_multi_delimiter(items, delimiter, num_wanted):
    keyfunc = MultiDelimiterKeyCallable(delimiter, num_wanted)

    return (list(item
                 for item in group
                 if item != delimiter)
            for key, group in itertools.groupby(items, keyfunc)
            if not key)

items = ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g']

print list(split_multi_delimiter(items, "X", 2))
```

I must say that cobbal's solution is much simpler for the same results.

Answer (score 4):

Use a generator function to maintain state of your iterator through the list, and the count of the number of separator chars seen so far:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g'] 

def splitOn(ll, x, n):
    cur = []
    splitcount = 0
    for c in ll:
        if c == x:
            splitcount += 1
            if splitcount == n:
                yield cur
                cur = []
                splitcount = 0
        else:
            cur.append(c)
            splitcount = 0
    yield cur

print list(splitOn(l, 'X', 2))
print list(splitOn(l, 'X', 1))
print list(splitOn(l, 'X', 3))

l += ['X','X']
print list(splitOn(l, 'X', 2))
print list(splitOn(l, 'X', 1))
print list(splitOn(l, 'X', 3))
```

prints:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']]
[['a', 'b'], [], ['c', 'd'], [], ['f'], ['g']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g'], []]
[['a', 'b'], [], ['c', 'd'], [], ['f'], ['g'], [], []]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']]
```

EDIT: I'm also a big fan of groupby, here's my go at it:

```
from itertools import groupby
def splitOn(ll, x, n):
    cur = []
    for isdelim,grp in groupby(ll, key=lambda c:c==x):
        if isdelim:
            nn = sum(1 for c in grp)
            while nn >= n:
                yield cur
                cur = []
                nn -= n
        else:
            cur.extend(grp)
    yield cur
```

Not too different from my earlier answer, just lets groupby take care of iterating over the input list, creating groups of delimiter-matching and not-delimiter-matching characters.  The non-matching characters just get added onto the current element, the matching character groups do the work of breaking up new elements.  For long lists, this is probably a bit more efficient, as groupby does all its work in C, and still only iterates over the list once.

Comment: I like this, like a ruby way to do it.

Comment: Nice. Very similar to the accepted answer but with generators.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g']
b = [[b for b in q if b != 'X'] for q in "".join(a).split("".join(['X' for i in range(2)]))]
```

this gives

`[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']]`

where the 2 is the number of elements you want. there is most likely a better way to do this.

Comment: Note that this only works if each element is a single character.

Answer (score 2):

Very ugly, but I wanted to see if I could pull this off as a one-liner and I thought I would share. I beg you not to actually use this solution for anything of any importance though. The `('X', 3)` at the end is the delimiter and the number of times it should be repeated.

```
(lambda delim, count: map(lambda x:filter(lambda y:y != delim, x), reduce(lambda x, y: (x[-1].append(y) if y != delim or x[-1][-count+1:] != [y]*(count-1) else x.append([])) or x, ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g'], [[]])))('X', 2)
```

**EDIT**

Here's a breakdown. I also eliminated some redundant code that was far more obvious when written out like this. (changed above also)

```
# Wrap everything in a lambda form to avoid repeating values
(lambda delim, count:
    # Filter all sublists after construction
    map(lambda x: filter(lambda y: y != delim, x), reduce(
        lambda x, y: (
            # Add the value to the current sub-list
            x[-1].append(y) if
                # but only if we have accumulated the
                # specified number of delimiters
                y != delim or x[-1][-count+1:] != [y]*(count-1) else

                # Start a new sublist
                x.append([]) or x,
        ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g'], [[]])
    )
)('X', 2)
```

Comment: Awesome! Awful! Awesome! Awful!  +1, but not sure this answer really counts as "useful".

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Agreed. I would understand a -1 as well. This answer definitely shouldn't be accepted anyway.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Cleaned things up a bit to the point where the answer is almost viable.

Comment: Because the code is wrapped in parentheses, you don't need all the backslashes.

Comment: @EthanFurman Right you are :) I just got so used to dropping them in with similar examples where they are required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clean nice solution using zip and generators

```
#1 define traditional sequence split function 
#if you only want it for lists, you can use indexing to make it shorter
def split(it, x):
    to_yield = []
    for y in it:
        if x == y:
            yield to_yield
            to_yield = []
        else:
            to_yield.append(y)
    if to_yield:
        yield to_yield

#2 zip the sequence with its tail 
#you could use itertools.chain to avoid creating unnecessary lists
zipped = zip(l, l[1:] + [''])

#3. remove ('X',not 'X')'s from the resulting sequence, and leave only the first position of each
# you can use list comprehension instead of generator expression
filtered = (x for x,y in zipped if not (x == 'X' and y != 'X'))

#4. split the result using traditional split
result = [x for x in split(filtered, 'X')]
```

This way  split() is more reusable.

It's surprising python doesn't have one built in.

edit:

You can easily adjust it for longer split sequences, repeating steps 2-3 and zipping filtered with l[i:] for 0< i <= n.

Comment: and yeah, i know it's slow. but a solution nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

```
import re    
map(list, re.sub('(?<=[a-z])X(?=[a-z])', '', ''.join(lst)).split('XX'))
```

This does a list -> string -> list conversion and assumes that the non-delimiter characters are all lower case letters.

Comment: Couldn't you get rid of the assumption if you changed the regex to `(?<=[^X])X(?=[^X])`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this:

```
def split_multi_delimiter(items, delimiter, num_wanted):
    def remove_delimiter(objs):
        return [obj for obj in objs if obj != delimiter]

    ranges = [(index, index+num_wanted) for index in xrange(len(items))
              if items[index:index+num_wanted] == [delimiter] * num_wanted]

    last_end = 0
    for range_start, range_end in ranges:
        yield remove_delimiter(items[last_end:range_start])
        last_end = range_end

    yield remove_delimiter(items[last_end:])

items = ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g']
print list(split_multi_delimiter(items, "X", 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: input = ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'cc', 'XX', 'd', 'X', 'ee', 'X', 'X', 'f']

In [7]: [s.strip('_').split('_') for s in '_'.join(input).split('X_X')]
Out[7]: [['a', 'b'], ['cc', 'XX', 'd', 'X', 'ee'], ['f']]
```

This assumes you can use a reserved character such as `_` which is not found in the input.

Comment: It also assumes the items can all be converted to characters.

Comment: True. I made that assumption after seeing only characters in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Too clever by half, and only offered because the obvious right way to do it seems so brute-force and ugly:

```
class joiner(object):
  def __init__(self, N, data = (), gluing = False):
    self.data = data
    self.N = N
    self.gluing = gluing
  def __add__(self, to_glue):
    # Process an item from itertools.groupby, by either
    # appending the data to the last item, starting a new item,
    # or changing the 'gluing' state according to the number of
    # consecutive delimiters that were found.
    N = self.N
    data = self.data
    item = list(to_glue[1])
    # A chunk of delimiters;
    # return a copy of self with the appropriate gluing state.
    if to_glue[0]: return joiner(N, data, len(item) < N)
    # Otherwise, handle the gluing appropriately, and reset gluing state.
    a, b = (data[:-1], data[-1] if data else []) if self.gluing else (data, [])
    return joiner(N, a + (b + item,))

def split_on_multiple(data, delimiter, N):
  # Split the list into alternating groups of delimiters and non-delimiters,
  # then use the joiner to join non-delimiter groups when the intervening
  # delimiter group is short.
  return sum(itertools.groupby(data, delimiter.__eq__), joiner(N)).data
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex, I choose you!

```
import re

def split_multiple(delimiter, input):
    pattern = ''.join(map(lambda x: ',' if x == delimiter else ' ', input))
    filtered = filter(lambda x: x != delimiter, input)
    result = []
    for k in map(len, re.split(';', ''.join(re.split(',',
        ';'.join(re.split(',{2,}', pattern)))))):
        result.append([])
        for n in range(k):
            result[-1].append(filtered.__next__())
    return result

print(split_multiple('X',
    ['a', 'b', 'X', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'f', 'X', 'g']))
```

Oh, you said Python, not Perl.