# Splitting python list between 2 values

Tags: python, list

[0,
 100,
 7,
 27,
 34,
 40,
 41,
 48,
 58,
 65,
 75,
 78,
 79,
 96,
 126,
 127,
 0,
 0,
 2,
 45,
 54,
 56,
 57,
 59,
 66,
 67,
 82,
 86,
 102,
 124,
 133,
 0,
 0,
 35,
 39,
 52,
 53,
 60,
 61,
 80,
 81,
 83,
 87,
 97,
 98,
 101,
 109,
 0,
 0,
 15,
 28,
 29,
 30,
 31,
 32,
 33,
 37,
 38,
 49,
 50,
 51,
 71,
 95,
 0,
 0,
 3,
 16,
 22,
 23,
 44,
 72,
 73,
 74,
 90,
 110,
 131,
 0,
 0,
 10,
 11,
 18,
 19,
 36,
 55,
 89,
 93,
 94,
 108,
 113,
 114,
 0,
 0,
 1,
 5,
 6,
 9,
 12,
 17,
 24,
 43,
 64,
 77,
 85,
 88,
 91,
 92,
 111,
 112,
 130,
 0,
 0,
 13,
 20,
 42,
 62,
 68,
 84,
 99,
 104,
 116,
 119,
 125,
 128,
 129,
 132,
 0,
 0,
 8,
 14,
 26,
 63,
 69,
 70,
 103,
 105,
 123,
 0,
 0,
 4,
 21,
 25,
 46,
 47,
 106,
 107,
 115,
 117,
 118,
 120,
 121,
 122,
 0,
 0,
 76,
 0]

I have this list of values and I want to split is between every two zeroes.

So my list will look like this:

[0, 100, 7, 27, 34, 40, 41, 48, 58, 65, 75, 78, 79, 96, 126, 127, 0],[ 0, 2, 45, 54, 56, 57, 59, 66, 67, 82, 86, 102, 124, 133, 0],[ 0, 35, 39, 52, 53, 60, 61, 80, 81, 83, 87, 97, 98, 101, 109, 0],[ 0, 15, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 37, 38, 49, 50, 51, 71, 95, 0],[ 0, 3, 16, 22, 23, 44, 72, 73, 74, 90, 110, 131, 0][ 0, 10, 11, 18, 19, 36, 55, 89, 93, 94, 108, 113, 114, 0],[ 0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 12, 17, 24, 43, 64, 77, 85, 88, 91, 92, 111, 112, 130, 0],[ 0, 13, 20, 42, 62, 68, 84, 99, 104, 116, 119, 125, 128, 129, 132, 0],[ 0, 8, 14, 26, 63, 69, 70, 103, 105, 123, 0],[ 0, 4, 21, 25, 46, 47, 106, 107, 115, 117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 0][ 0, 76, 0]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't expect us to write code for you, rather to help you get to the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most Pythonic Way to Split an Array by Repeating Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530210/most-pythonic-way-to-split-an-array-by-repeating-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a simple `for` loop with the built-in function `zip`:

```
# l is your list
result = [[l[0]]]
for i, j in  zip(l[1:], l):
    if i == 0 == j:
        result.append([i])
    else:
        result[-1].append(i)
result
```

output:

```
[[0, 100, 7, 27, 34, 40, 41, 48, 58, 65, 75, 78, 79, 96, 126, 127, 0],
 [0, 2, 45, 54, 56, 57, 59, 66, 67, 82, 86, 102, 124, 133, 0],
 [0, 35, 39, 52, 53, 60, 61, 80, 81, 83, 87, 97, 98, 101, 109, 0],
 [0, 15, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 37, 38, 49, 50, 51, 71, 95, 0],
 [0, 3, 16, 22, 23, 44, 72, 73, 74, 90, 110, 131, 0],
 [0, 10, 11, 18, 19, 36, 55, 89, 93, 94, 108, 113, 114, 0],
 [0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 12, 17, 24, 43, 64, 77, 85, 88, 91, 92, 111, 112, 130, 0],
 [0, 13, 20, 42, 62, 68, 84, 99, 104, 116, 119, 125, 128, 129, 132, 0],
 [0, 8, 14, 26, 63, 69, 70, 103, 105, 123, 0],
 [0, 4, 21, 25, 46, 47, 106, 107, 115, 117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 0],
 [0, 76, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to do this:

```py
outputList=[]
start = 0

for i in range(len(myList) - 1):
    curr = myList[i]
    next = myList[i+1]
    if curr == 0 and next == 0:
        outputList.append(myList[start:i+1]
        start = i+1
```

I think that will do the job, let me now if that worked! :D